# CSS absolute positioning dilemma

Tags: css, positioning

I'm very experienced with CSS but this one has me confused - apologies if it is a simple fix.

I am attempting to theme a Drupal webform which has multiple fieldsets. The idea is to stack the fieldsets on top of each other. A fairly simple CSS issue of positioning relatively and absolutely - but it goes very wrong as the containing div collapses instead of maintaining it's shape.

I set the `background-color` of the fieldsets to green. The containing border has a red border and is positioned relatively.

When the fieldsets are positioned absolutely, they stack as I expect but the containing DIV collapses and compromises the rest of the sites styling.

Comment: your fieldsets are appearing stacked. What browser are you viewing in?

Comment: Is this a simple situation in which a clearfix is required? I haven't had time to look into this case, but sounds like a clearfix-type-delio to me.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Investigating clearfix now

Comment: When I add `position: absolute` to `fieldset` on your site, the expected result happens. The absolutely positioned elements are removed from normal flow, so the height of the containing `div` is not increased by the `fieldset`s any longer.

Comment: Clearfix won't help. All modern browsers will do the same thing here. Rhyso has misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot: totally agree that removing the fieldset from normal flow means the containing DIV does not increase in height. But, I need a solution so that it does and the submit button (in the blue div) sits nicely beneath the fieldsets

Comment: Well, evidently you're going to do something more than just have the `fieldset`s all sat on top of each other. What's the endgame here?

Comment: Now that the example link has died, this question is off-topic. Please always add a [mcve] into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just put a height onto the containing div using css?

Or use some javascript to grab the height of the tallest fieldset and make the containing div that height?

Or do it dynamically for each fieldset starting with the first one then when you move onto anotjher fieldset the javascript gets it's height and sets the container div to that height and so on.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Brilliant suggestion which could have taken me hours to think of. Thanks again